# How virtual/abstract methods are displayed in class diagrams?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, uml, class-diagram

First, I am coming from the Java community, and still a learner in C++.

Please have a look at the following classes

[image]

[image]

The second picture shows a sub class of the class "GameObject". It also has a `Display()` method. There are 5 sub classes of the class GameObject, and they all have this `Display()` method. So, is this display method in `GameObject` is a virtual one?

I think it is not abstract virtual (100% virtual)  because the `Display()` in `GameObject` displays some texts in `GameObject.cpp`

Anyway, I am not quite sure. Please help!

Comment: Does `Display` have the `virtual` specifier in `GameObject`?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Hi, no there is no code. I am the person who is going to implement it, this is the diagram I am supplied with

Comment: If 'there is no code', where did you get the 'texts in GameObject.cpp'?

Comment: @KendallFrey: The document says the Display method in GameObject need to display text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, virtual functions are virtual if and only if the have been explicitly declared virtual in a base class or the class itself. Since GameObject seems to have no base class, `GameObject::Display()` hast to be declared virtual, if displaying a GameObject reference (or pointer) should behave according to actual (i.e. runtime) type of the object behind that reference.
Having a function body in GameObject.cpp does not mean the function is not pure virtual (the C++ equivalent for java's abstract). You can make the function pure virtual by adding a `= 0` to its declaration. Nevertheless you can provide a implementation for pure virtual methods, e.g. to have a default implementation that you explicitly call in derived classes implementing the method:

```
class GameObject { 
  //...
public:
  virtual void Display() = 0;
};

//GameObject.cpp
void GameObject::Display() { 
  /* do something */ 
}

//DerivedGO.h
class DerivedGO : public GameObject {
public:
  // virtual can be left out here, since it's declared virtual in the base class
  virtual void Display() {
    prepDisplay(); // do some preparation
    GameObject::Display(); //call the original/default implementation
  }
};
```

However be aware that making a function pure virtual means making the containing class abstract and every derived class as well that does not override all pure virtual functions from its base classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to implement the class. There is no existing code. Before  I do I need to know whether the class is having that method abstract or virtual. I am the person who is going to do it. So is that method is virtual?

Comment: @Yohan, if this was Java, would you specify the method in the base class `final`? If not, that means you expect sub-classes to override it and it should be virtual in C++. Now ask yourself if the method is abstract in Java (has no implementation). If so, mark it pure virtual in C++ and provide no body.

Comment: @Yohan I updated the answer, but maybe you should as well consult the textbook of your choice regarding virtual methods.

Comment: OK, I will treat it s abstract virtual then. Thank you :)